# Integrating lucky orange in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react.js, and I'm trying to integrate [lucky orange](https://www.luckyorange.com/) into my web app. Where should I paste the javascript snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As most analytics, you should parse their javascript sample last of the `<head>` tag on your index.html. It doesn't matter which framework you are using as it will wait for the loaded event to be triggered.

From [luckyorange documentation](https://help.luckyorange.com/article/95-installation-guides#basic) :

> Paste your tracking code into your page's source file just before the closing  tag. Most websites re-use one file for common content (e.g. a page template), so it's likely you won't have to place the code snippet on every page of your website.

Also, you have **legal obligation** to mention your users about the **use of cookies** to track their use (always good to remind )

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was wondering whether you know the answer to this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58677380/how-to-set-samesite-none-with-react-js