# How to set SameSite-None with react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am using react.js, and I'm trying to integrate [lucky orange](https://www.luckyorange.com/) into my web app. I added the code snippet in the head tag of the `index.html` file, but I get a warning saying:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://luckyorange.net/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

Also, when testing to see [whether lucky orange is working or not](https://help.luckyorange.com/article/85-how-do-i-know-if-i-set-up-lucky-orange-correctly), it says to search for the term "lo_site_id" in the "view page source". I did that, but nothing came up. Am I setting it up wrong?

**Question**

How can I properly set the SameSite=None and secure, and why am I not seeing `lo_site_id`? (I'm not using node. This is front end only)

Comment: Looks like you've posted the same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58686839/3020057 I would probably close this one and add additional info / tags to the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SameSite Cookie Attribute Warning Isn't getting fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686839/samesite-cookie-attribute-warning-isnt-getting-fixed)

Comment: a same-site cookie is supposed to be added by the backend. you happen to see the error because you are on chrome. On firefox or safari, you won't see that. Lucky Orange should update their cookies for this purpose. It looks like a tracking feature or something.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and fixed by changing the cookie creation a bit:

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set(key1, value1, {secure: true, sameSite: 'none'});
cookies.set(key2, value2, {secure: true, sameSite: 'none'});
```

So added the last parameter, setting the cookie options.

My app uses the the universal-cookie package, you can find the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie

I don't know the lucky-orange app, if it is setting the cookie, you might need to tweak the code of that embedded app.

BTW. Chrome/Edge(90) throw error now (i.e. won't save the incorrect cookies), whereas Firefox(88) is not so strict and only logs a warning.